# setText after TextWatcher on a programatically created EditText

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, settext

Have have an app where I programatically create LinearLayouts. The LinearLayouts differ a little bit, but they all contain several views. Some of them have a EditText-field with a TextWatcher. When these views are created, I want to use an old, stored value from preferences  in the EditText-field.

When I use .setText(old_value) before the TextWtacher, the data in the EditText-field is correct, but the calulations denpending on the TextWatcher-function is never invoked. 
When I try to use .setText(old_value) after the TextWtacher, I get a NullPointerException.

Below are a short example of code...

```
(LinearLayout) linearLayout = new LinearLayout();
linearLayout.setId(ll_counter++);
while (have more rows to process) {
    BUTTON-VIEW-code;
    linearLayout.addView();
    TEXT-VIEW-code
    linearLayout.addView(TEXT-VIEW);

    editText = new EditText(this);
    editText.setId(et_counter++);
    editText.setTag("SomeTag");
    editText.setText(old_value); // Works, but no calculations
    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // do calculations and update add_text-field.
        }
        public void beforeTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // nothing here
        }
        public void onTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // nothing here
        }

    });
    editText.setText(old_value); // Doesn't Works, NULL PONTER EXCEPTION
    linearLayout.addView(editText);
}
```

Should the editText.setText come after linearLayout.addView(editText); like this? (With some modifcations of course...)

```
linearLayout.addView(editText);
editText.setText(old_value);
```

Comment: Not sure if creating a `TextWatcher` inside a while loop is the best bet. Remember that text watcher will always be there for you unless you get rid of it yourself. You might be having problems because you keep making new TextWatchers when you really want just one.

Comment: editText.setId(et_counter++); && linearLayout.setId(ll_counter++); look a bit risky too, depending on the default values of et_counter and ll_counter. Also as @pasta12 mentioned, adding TextWatcher inside a loop doesn't make much sense. Based on your logic, it appears you only need one TextWatcher where as you are creating multiples.

Comment: Pasta12, I'll look into that. Because, as you say, all I need is one TextWtacher. And @Gaurav Arora, I have more dependible ids than created in this example... But thanx to both for reply

Comment: .setText(), before addTextChangedListener() works               .setTest() after addTextChangedListener() raises NPE. The only reason I see is something wrong in your TextWatcher methods. Can you please post your NPE stack trace or the source code for the TextWatcher.

Comment: @Gaurav Arora In order to access data from editText.setTag() and editText.setID() and so forth, I'm using >View v = getCurrentFocus();< inside afterTextChanged. And i guess since the view is not yet added to the stack (or what ever), setText AFTER TextWatcher will fail...

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer to your own question, _NOT_ add it to the question, as it makes it quite useless for any user user of SO.

Answer (score 0):

create `edittext` outside of the while loop

```
editText = new EditText(this);

 while (have more rows to process) {
    BUTTON-VIEW-code;
    linearLayout.addView();
    TEXT-VIEW-code
    linearLayout.addView(TEXT-VIEW);
```

Comment: Not an option since the loop potentially creates several edittext-fields that needs a TextWatcher. Each linearLayout can have an editText...

Comment: I could of course store the editText-ids in an array an apply them after the while-loop...

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: Totally restructured the code and found some errors where there was a reference inside the TextWatcher to a textField that not yet had been initiated. Although i thought so since

```
TextView textfield = new TextView(this);
```

was done before the editText-field and that textfield was added to the LinearLayout before the editText-field like this :

```
linearLayout.addView(textfield);
```

Most likely a newbie error...